# Disable auto generated JAX-WS Status Page

Tags: web-services, tomcat, jax-ws

When I deploy and run my web service developed with JAX-WS I can see a summary page with some info on it, something like in this picture:

<sub>http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/</sub>
[image: Web service status page]

For the final implementation we would like to remove this page so that a custom or a blank page is returned while still having access to the web service endpoint.

We are currently running on Tomcat.

Answer (score 4):

There is a field on the [`WSServlet`](http://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/jax-ws-20-fcs/arch/com/sun/xml/ws/transport/http/servlet/WSServlet.html) class that might do what you are looking for: `JAXWS_RI_PROPERTY_PUBLISH_STATUS_PAGE` (it's value is `com.sun.xml.ws.server.http.publishStatusPage`).

Looking at the source code from a JAX-WS download it seems that you need to set it as a context parameter in your `web.xml` file:

```
<web-app>
  <context-param>
     <param-name>com.sun.xml.ws.server.http.publishStatusPage</param-name>
     <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  ...
```

Seems that [`HttpAdapter`](http://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/jax-ws-20-fcs/arch/com/sun/xml/ws/transport/http/HttpAdapter.html) had something similar on it but was taken from an environment variable:

```
setPublishStatus(
    System.getProperty(HttpAdapter.class.getName() + ".publishStatusPage")
    .equals("true"));
```

The code on `HttpAdapter` is marked deprecated in the javadoc so the context parameter seems the way to go.

Comment: +1 as I just tried this and it worked: it yields a blank page instead of the status page, but accessing the service or wsdl still works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to solve this for two days, Glassfish 3.1.2.
The only solution was to have
    `-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.publishStatusPage=false`
I know its old, but wantd to maintain the knowledge. Hope this helps any one with this issue.

Comment: The same was said earlier in @bogdan's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18475070/666414

Answer (score 0):

I have completed the same task for WebLogic recently. 
It was requested to hide/show a status page of a public web service depending on a target environment i.e. hide for production, show for dev. 
Nothing of the previous answers worked for me. 
The success solution is based on implementation of javax.servlet.Filter.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.HttpMethod;


@WebFilter(urlPatterns = { "/WeblogicWebService" })
public class FilterStatusSoapPage implements Filter {

     @Value("${soap.status.page.disabled}")
     private boolean flagDisablePublishStatusPage;

     public void doFilter(
            ServletRequest request, 
            ServletResponse response, 
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            HttpServletResponse httpRes = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            String queryString = httpReq.getQueryString();
            if(flagDisablePublishStatusPage)
             if(queryString == null || queryString.trim().isEmpty())
                if(HttpMethod.GET.matches(httpReq.getMethod())) {
                    httpRes.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                    httpRes.getWriter().write("Access to status page of Web 
                                        Service is not allowed");
                    httpRes.getWriter().flush();
                    httpRes.getWriter().close();
                    return; 
                } 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error on FilterStatusSoapPage filter");
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {}
    public void destroy() {}
}
```